# Маршрутизация Kohana

Tags: route, маршрутизация, kohana

Можно ли сделать роут, который будет выглядеть примерно так:

somesite.com/post/1

Где post - контроллер, экшн - index (установлен по умолчанию, он должен пропускаться), и 1 - параметр id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно.

```
Route::set('your_route', '<controller>/<id>')
->defaults(array(
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Объясняю. Маршрут получит параметры, указанные в треугольных скобках, из адреса. Всё, что он оттуда не получит попробует взять из значений по-умолчанию, указанных в массиве, который передается методву `defaults`.

Можно усложнить пример:

```
Route::set('your_route', '<controller>/<id>', array('id' => '[0-9]+'))
->defaults(array(
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Тут мы передаем необязательный массив регулярок для полей. Так, в данном случае, `id` может быть только числовым.

Или еще сложнее:

```
Route::set('your_route', '<controller>/<id>',
    array('controller' => '(post|another|sample)', 'id' => '[0-9]+')
)->defaults(array(
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

В данном случае пройдут только роуты с контроллерами `post`, `another`, `sample`

Comment: Можно как-то назвать треугольную скобку по-умному? :)

Comment: Пробовал и так, но, увы, всё-равно не работает:

Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL post/1 was not found on this server.

Версия 3.3.0

Насчёт треугольной скобки - разве что знак больше / меньше. По-другому никак наверное :))

Comment: А если обратиться на прямую к тому же контроллеру, т.е. post/index/1
то всё работает как надо )

Comment: Вы же этот маршрут описываете до других, которые могут его перекрыть? Пропишите его первым, хотя бы на время.

Comment: Где ж вы были раньше, спасибо огромное!
Всё работает :)

Comment: Да я вроде и так не заставил себя ждать)
Удачного изучения.